# Creating responsive menus not working

Tags: html, css

I'm in the process of creating a personal website so I'm not 100% sure what the content breakpoints will be. I'm using 320px (phone), 768px (tablet), and 1024px (desktop) for now. I don't know if I need one specific to tablets as they can probably use full screen, but I have it in place just in case.

I'm having trouble showing the menu links inline when at full screen and I can't figure out how to get a drop down menu when in mobile view mode. I have the meta viewport set to device-width, and 1.

I would like the in-line mode to hover over each one to show a background color with 8px x 20px padded. I'm trying to avoid javascript and jquery all together if possible. And without floats too.

**HTML**

```
<nav class="nav-menu" role="navigation">

  <ul>
    <li><a class="blue" href="" title="Home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a class="red" href="" title="Blog">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a class="green" href="" title="Contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>

  <a href="#" id="pull"></a>

</nav>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xpu9bxjc/

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Don't set breakpoints for devices...set them for when your design **needs** them...if  that happens to be at 743.25px so be it.

Comment: I agree with @Paulie_D. Also, in your fiddle, it looks like you have the mobile style for medium+ screens, while your non-mobile style is shown if you shrink the screen to a mobile size. Change your media query to `max-width` instead of `min-width` to correct this.

Comment: I reversed the min/max and got it working the way i want it in regards to displaying inline on larger screens. However, how can I set the drop down in mobile mode?

Comment: Also, wouldn't min-width be better, as it can scale to higher resolutions as they become available on devices? Or does it not make a difference?

Comment: It's just a matter of how you want to apply your styles. If you use min-width, inside that media query you would supply styles for screen sizes >= the value you specify, then smaller screens would use the default styles outside of your media query. If you use max-width, then inside that media query you would supply styles for screen sizes <= the value you specify, then larger screens would use the default styles outside of your media query.

Comment: It depends on which screen-size you want to focus on. I believe the more common approach is to design your site for medium or large screen sizes, then determine breakpoints and use max-width media queries to supply styles for tablet and mobile views.

Comment: That way you can include all the content you want on a large size screen, then scale down components, or remove unnecessary ones to better utilize screen space on smaller devices.

Answer (score 0):

In your fiddle, you have your mobile menu showing up on screen sizes that are medium and up, while your non-mobile menu is showing when you shrink to a mobile size screen.

To fix this, change your media query from:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) {
```

to:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
```

For adding the hover effect, you want to add `:hover` to your selector, then apply whatever styles you want on hover in there.

```
.nav-menu a:hover {
    /* put hover styles here */
}
```

Updated these in your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xpu9bxjc/2/).

Comment: Awesome. I will try this out tonight and see how it works. Thanks!